# Azure Logic App - Simple Email Template for JSON Request Body

Tags: azure, sendgrid, azure-logic-apps, email-templates

I've got a simple Azure Logic App, which receives and emails out JSON data in a very basic HTML table format (created with a `convertToTableAction`).

Does anyone know of a way to instead send this out using an email template?

I've got a SendGrid account set up with my Azure subscription, but there doesn't seem to be any way to specify a template id with the `Send email (v2)` action in Logic apps.

I can't quite see how I'd edit the Logic App code to use the only SendGrid api that seems to support sending templates [V3](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html) either. (It is my first Logic app though, so I could well be missing a trick)

Really, any advice on how to send out a templated email would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that the logic app integrate the Sendgrid(V2) currently. You could give your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps) to Azure team.

If [azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) is acceptable, you could [add and run custom code for logic apps through Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions)

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the feedback. I know I could go down the Azure function route, but the Logic apps seemed very configurable (and I just wanted to have a play with them), so for the simple case I had in mind (put json data into a nicely formatted email) it seemed like they should be up to the job. I'll try the direct Azure feature request portal though, thanks. Do you know of any other useful sites for getting help on Azure features?

Answer (score 0):

there is two way to do it ..

1) Using SendGrid Connector :

- You need to create one azure function or web API pass request as your JSON outout string  and replace with html content and get html in response
- Pass html response in body of the  send email  action  of SendGrid Connector
- [Details of SendGrid Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sendgrid)
- [Please refer this link for Json data replaced to html](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/send-email-using-templates-in-asp-net-core-applications/)

my explanation is very short but if you don't understand then i will help you in details